# MySQL синхронизация между двумя БД

Tags: mysql

Как можно настроить синхронизация между двумя базами? обе базы находятся на разных машинах. Одна на **веб хостинге** (как я понял, изменить что-то в файлах не могу(**это и ограничивает**)), вторая находится на **VDS.** Принцип и зачем оно нужно - к примеру, происходит регистрация через веб на **DB1**. **DB2** делает запрос на синхронизация к **DB1** и проверяет, есть ли изменения в таблице, если да, то закидывает изменения к себе. По сути, он просто копирует **DB1** для **DB2**.
Делается для того, что для стабильной работы на VDS, требуется постоянное подключение к базам, а вебхостинг **такого не может** и **timeout стоит на 30 секунд**, изменить **нельзя.** Возможно нужен скрипт для DB2, чтобы тот копировал или посылал запрос? Спасибо!
[image: пример]

Comment: Если уже есть VDS, то почему бы не отказаться от веб-хостинга вообще?

Answer (score 1):

replication это единственный здоровый способ синхронизации данных между разными базами данных.

перегоняйте "вебхостинг" на "VDS" и настраиваёте между двумя серверами репликацию.